# Using accepts_nested_attributes_for outside of proper restful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a setup wizard for a model called Project. This model has a lot of associated information, which includes a number of nested models.

After some research and a fair bit of trial and error, I decided to manage the setup process in a `SetupController`, using the `:id` parameter to track which step I'm on, resulting in a path pattern like so: `projects/:project_id/setup/:id/edit` (based on [this blog](http://andymaleh.blogspot.ca/2013/10/ultra-light-maintainable-wizards-in.html))

Here are the relevant bits:

Project Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: -> x { x[:value].blank? }
end
```

Rating Model

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has a null: false constraint on value
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Setup Controller

```
ProjectSetupController < ApplicationController
  STEPS = %w(step_1 step_2 step_3)

  layout 'setups'

  def edit
    @project.ratings.build
    render step
  end

  def update
    if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
      if next_step && params[:button].downcase.include?('continue')
        redirect_to edit_project_setup_path(@project, next_step), flash: {success: "Updated project"}
      else
        redirect_to project_path(@project)
      end
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Please complete all required fields"
      render step
    end
  end

  private

  def step
    STEPS.find {|s| s == params[:id].to_s.downcase}
  end

  def current_step_index
    STEPS.index(step)
  end

  def next_step
    STEPS[current_step_index+1]
  end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name, ratings_attributes: [:id, :value, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

And this is all well and good, except when it comes to nested attributes. A Project `accepts_nested_attributes_for Ratings`, but rejects any ratings with blank values. I want the user to be able to submit a form with blank values because multiple rating fields can be added dynamically to the project form and there will always be an empty `new` field, I just don't want any record without a value to be saved. However, something gets muddled when using the :id parameter as something other than the id of the parent model, and these records are not discarded when the form is submitted. Instead, they hit the Rating database validation for presence of value and an error is thrown.

Form

```
 = simple_form_for @project, url: project_setup_path(@project, params[:id]), as: :project, html: {id: 'customization-form'} do |f|

  - @project.ratings.each do |rating|
    .rating-wrapper{class: rating.new_record? && "new"}

      = f.fields_for :ratings, rating do |ff|     
        = ff.input_field :value, placeholder: "Enter New Rating"

   = button_tag(type: 'submit') do
     Update
```

If I mock a submission with the params[:id] as the id of the project I'm submitting the form for, then everything works as expected (of course this results in a redirect error as the project id is not a valid step), so I feel like there must be some way to point the attributes to the correct id, alas, this magic is beyond me.

Current possible workarounds:

- I can submit the form to the regular project controller action with a
  button parameter that will redirect the user back into the setup
  process
- I could remove the empty value fields from the DOM via javascript on
  submission
- If I remove the Rating validations, I can submit the form as
  is, and all blank ratings will be saved, but I could delete them in a
  callback

Currently I'm employing the first workaround, but is there a more Rails-y solution that allows me to keep this process within the setup controller, without removing database validations or using javascript? The [blog article](http://andymaleh.blogspot.ca/2013/10/ultra-light-maintainable-wizards-in.html) I modeled my wizard after suggested sub-models for handling interim validations - I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for here, but maybe there's a way I could leverage something like that?